# FastCGI Shibboleth responder should only be used for Shibboleth protocol requests

Tags: lighttpd

Following this https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPFastCGIConfig

guide to setting up shibboleth for lighttpd, get error

```
"FastCGI Shibboleth responder should only be used for Shibboleth protocol requests."
```

when accessing /Shibboleth.sso/handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that handlerSSL attribute in shibboleth2.xml was set to true, but I was accessing it over http connection. Set

```
handlerSSL="false"
```

Also on ubuntu https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/322 patch had to be installed.